# How can I add a prototype function to an event listener in the initialization function?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase my question, so let me present an example:

```
function foo() {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        bar(event.keycode);
}

foo.prototype.bar = function (keycode) {
//code
}
```

I've tried using `this.bar()`, but that results in using the `window` as `this`. Is there a way to do this, or will I have to call another initialize method manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind `this.bar` to `this` before you pass it.

```
function foo() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.bar.bind(this), false);
}


foo.prototype.bar = function (event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/2tee4/

Comment: Why bind ? `window.addEventListener("keydown", this.bar, false);` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera, so that `bar` gets called in the context of `this`, otherwise it'll be executed in global scope and there wont be an advantage to having bound a prototype function.

Comment: @SheikhHeera `.bind` fixes `this` value to be always the same no matter how the bound function is called. In this case, it will always be the `foo` object.

Comment: @Esailija, I think `bar` is already in the `foo's` prototype so it's always bound to `foo`, sorry may be I'm missing something.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, functions passed by reference (i.e. `this.bar`) do not retain any sort of reference to its context. `a = { foo: function(){...}}; b = {foo:a.foo}; b.foo();` will call `foo` with a `this` value of `b`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera functions normally aren't bound to anything. You can easily test that when you do it like `this.bar`, `this` will be `window` once the event is fired, that was even said in the question.

Comment: @Esailija, SheikhHeera isn't OP.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: There [are no methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) in javascript which are "bound" to anything.

Comment: Lol...! I made a confussion, sorry for that but thank you guys. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate response, this is just what I needed! I now also know about bind(), seems like an excellent tool... In fact, I'm off to re-factor some code...

Comment: As a word of caution, in all the provided examples, you'll need to retain a reference to the bound function or object if you intend on unbinding it later. `foo.bind(bar) !== foo.bind(bar)`

Comment: @zzzzBov good catch. I usually do `this.bar = this.bar.bind(this)` as the first thing in constructor so it hasn't been an issue.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution if you don't have [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) available*, and you're unwilling to add extra functions to `Function.prototype` would be to close over the call to `this.bar`:

```
function foo() {
    var self;
    self = this;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        self.bar(e);
    }, false);
}
foo.prototype.bar = function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

<sub>* although your use of `addEventListener` without `attachEvent` leads me to believe that `Function.prototype.bind` would be an acceptable choice</sub>

---

Additionally, libraries such as `jQuery` may include their own form of `bind`, jQuery's is [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy).

Comment: Thanks for the extra options, it's always nice to have more information. Even more so when this becomes a search result on Google for someone else...

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to add a new listener for every `foo` created, another option is to make `foo` implement the *EventListener* interface, and simply pass `this` in place of the handler.

```
function Foo() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this, false);
}

Foo.prototype.bar = "foobar";

Foo.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);   // "mousedown" (for example)
    console.log(this.bar); // "foobar"
};

new Foo();
```

Note that this only works with `addEventListener()`.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/k93Pr/

Comment: +1, it would be awesome if jQuery supported this as well, would get rid of a lot of `$.proxy` boilerplate for me :)

Comment: Since the above comment got upvoted I'm gonna link my ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12031 :P

Comment: @Esailija: It'll be interesting to see if they implement it. I wouldn't wait for jQuery though. Just make it a plugin. Here's a simple and perhaps naive initial implementation. Just need to add support for the other signatures of `.on()`. http://jsfiddle.net/suQEZ/ *(I know you didn't need me to show you how. It's more for the sake of others.)*